# A tool for just compiling local code over remote machine without tear?

Tags: ubuntu, development-environment, remote-server

is there any tool to compile locally written code on remote workstation based linux? It is generally so slow and time consuming to coding over ssh or X11. Therefore I am looking fo an alternative tool to just compile the local code over remote machine. I write the code locally and send it to remote and see the result. I am looking for that kind of workaround>?

Comment: I don't understand. You want to transfer code to a computer, but want to ban the most common ways of transferring code or inputting code into a computer.

Comment: Lookup "remote compiler" I get tons of results with that search query.

Comment: I am looking for a tool that sends the written code to remote machine to be compiled and show the output of the code. That it, I write all the code locally with local IDE but the compilation will be handled over remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two common approaches that I have run across in such scenario. Both of them uses SSH.

1. Edit files on SSHFS
2. rsync files and build

### Edit files on SSHFS

In this option, your remote machine should run an SSH server. Your local machine would mount a directory from the remote machine using Fuse/SSHFS. You edit the code in your local machine and issue the build command over SSH.

### rsync files and build

In this option, your sources reside on the local machine. You checkout the sources on the local machine, edit them. Then you'll have a shell script that rsync your source to the remote machine over SSH and build over SSH.

In both cases, you'll have to translate the path outputted from the remote machine to the path on the local machine using sed or similar tool to make the error messages recognized and jump directly to the correct line in the editor.